# Command for Text Editor to make shortcut key

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'd like to make a shortcut key (Ctrl + Alt + N) for Text Editor in Ubuntu 21.10

I went to Settings > Keyboard > Customize Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts > +

then typed Text Editor for NAME, but don't know what to put for COMMAND.

Apologies if this has been asked.

New to Ubuntu and love it.

R.P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the console command is:

```
gnome-text-editor
```

write this where it asks for command

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I have one more shortcut I'd like to make. I installed a program called Vueprint. What would the COMMAND be for that?

Comment: I answered, but this type of thing is really easy to find searching in google. I think you must search a bit more before using the community to ask such trivial things. Have a nice day @R.P.

Comment: Sincere apologies. New to Ubuntu and community. Will search further. Thank you

Comment: This is a future proof answer. Once gedit is retired, this command will still be valid.